# What do you call a summer camp?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, expresiones, estados-unidos

I'm translating a flyer for a summer camp business into Spanish. I'm not a native speaker but I've been studying long enough to suspect that I should not translate "summer camp" as "campamento de verano."

Comment: Quite probably it depends on the country. In Argentina/Uruguay/Chile it's "colonia de verano" or "colonia de vacaciones", but I'm sure in other places that sounds strange.  Where would this be?

Comment: In Spain "campamento de verano" is a quite common expression, although it usually refers to the summer camps destined to kids. If you are in another country or you refer to a summer camp destined to adults you should use another expression. As a suggestion I'd recommend to add in your question details about the purpose of the summer camp and the country where the flyer is going to be published, as the answers may vary depending on that.

Comment: @Gaviota this would be in Los Angeles County, southern California in the United States.

Comment: @Charlie L.A., baby

Answer (score 2):

In Spain, we do say *campamento de verano* for summer camps.

Answer (score 0):

Campamento de verano suena bien. En Argentina lo llamábamos colonia de vacaciones.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21712)

Comment: How is it that this doesn't provide an answer?

Comment: That is the automated message which the Low Quality Posts queue inserts. It would be better with references although to be fair the existing answer similarly lacks justifications for its choice. The OP did ask specifically for usage in the southern US.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much.

Comment: Es un poco contraintuitivo para un usuario con poca experiencia que le digamos que su respuesta no vale cuando hay una muy parecida que ya tiene un par de votos. Cierto que la respuesta preexistente es anterior a los comentarios de clarificación del OP, pero no debemos que los usuarios con poca experiencia no saben lo que no saben.

Answer (score 0):

normally "summer camp" would translate to "campamento de verano"

I think it is the best option for native speakers to understand correctly what the brochure says.